# Serializing a Pointer using MFC CArchive (with mfc100d.dll, CMemFile)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am running into an issue serializing and deserializing pointer data in VS2010 VC++.  Basically, the program was unable to serialize and deserialize a CObList * pointer data.  The source code does the normal steps to handle the process:

1) MyObject was inherited from CObject;

2) We added DECLARE_SERIAL(MyObject) in the class declaration (1st line);

3) We added IMPLEMENT_SERIAL( MyObject, MyParentObject, SCHEMA_VERSION )

```
//Where MyParentObject is inherited from CObject (indirectly, there're a few more levels of objects), SCHEMA_VERSION is just a version control CONSTANT we use
```

4) Then we have overloaded

```
void MyObject::Serialize( CArchive& ar )
{
   BOOL b;
   .....
   ... (some other simple variables with default values)

   MyParentObject::Serialize(ar);

   if (ar.IsStoring())
   {
      ar << m_sTitle;
      ar << m_pObjectsList;
   }
   else
   {
      ar >> m_sTitle;
      ar >> m_pObjectsList;
   }
}
```

Note: MyParentObject::Serialize is implemented accordingly.  CObList * m_pObjectsList; is declared properly in the header file.

The program threw an Access Violation (First-chance exception at 0x52e77b2c (mfc100d.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004) when trying to deserialize from the "ar >> m_pObjectsList".

Then I started testing and changed the complex pointer m_pObjectsList to a simple pointer to CString.  Same error occur at the same time when deserializing the pointer to CString.  If I simply serialize and deserialize by CString (without the pointer), it works fine.  It seems like some pointer serializing is broken.

Maybe MFC100d doesn't work well with W32 program in a 64Bit OS Debugger? This is causing problem both in Debug mode and Release mode.  What's happening?  I've exhausted my resources and any direction or inspiration is much appreciated.  Thank you all ahead.

Comment: Did you initialize `m_pObjectsList`?

Comment: This is inherited legacy code base.  I see m_pObjectsList = new CObList; in a NewObjectsList method and m_pObjectsList = NULL; in constructor code.

Comment: I think that indicated that it was initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers can't be *serialized*.

There is no guarantee that

1. the application reading the file
   will have access to the same area of
   memory
2. the OS will put the data in the same
   place
3. the application reading the file
   will be placed in the same place in
   memory

One idea is to emulate pointers by using file offsets.  Thus an object is located at a position in the file relative to the beginning.  This is difficult.

A better idea is to write out **all** of the data and let the application reading the data place the data in memory.  This also gives the application freedom to use any data structure it wants for storing the data.

Comment: Agree - you need to serialize each object in the list, not the pointer to the list.

Comment: On and prior to MFC 6 (Visual Studio 6), the compiler was abled to handle this pointer serialization nicely.  I think all MFC comes after than tightened its memory allocation security/policy that broke this.

Comment: @Jerry:  You store pointers from your machine into a file.  I read the file onto my machine.  Will the pointers or values in the pointers, still be valid on my machine?  What if I'm running Windows NT and your running on a Mac?  There's just no guarantee that any operating system will load a program in the exact same place every time it is launched; thus the content of the pointer may not be valid.  Tooo risky.

Comment: I understand that.  However, it was actually not for storing purpose.  This was a legacy design that the manipulation of the data happens in the CMemFile which is a Serialized version of the object. Sigh... Legacy...  Too much re-write to get this complex object to do it without this approach.  But have to deal with it regardless.